# Size of a PK int in SQL Server / ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Currently, my primary key data type is an `int, not null`, and is defined as following from the application:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```

I am a bit worried though, since `int` is restricted, at some point, it will not be possible to add new rows because of the size of the primary key.

How should this problem be approached? I was thinking about a) simply changing the data type to long, etc. or, b) if possible, remove the primary key since it is not used at any time in the application?

Comment: With a type `INT`, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. If you insert one row **every second**, around the clock, every day of the year, you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

Comment: If that's not enough: use a `BIGINT`. If you insert **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't remove your primary key, you need it to identify records in your database.  If you expect to have more than int can handle, you can:

- Make it bigint
- Make it uniqueidentifier
- Make it a composite key (made up of two or more fields)

Comment: If you have that kind of big numbers (2*10^9) you should be very worried about the size of that primary key. Making it into a guid ... would be a bad idea. Just calculate the size of an index on that thing...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're dealing with very small tables (10 rows), you never want to go without a primary key.  The primary key dramatically affects performance as it provides your initial unique and clustered index.  Unique indexes play a vital role in maintaining data integrity.  Clustered indexes play a vital role in allowing SQL Server to perform index and row seeks instead of scans.  Basically, does it have to load one row or all of the rows.

Changing the data-type will affect your primary index size, row size, as well the size of as any index placed on the table.  Unless you're worried about exceeding 2,147,483,647 rows in the near future, I would stick with an INT.  Every data type has a restricted row count.

Comment: I think your last sentence is misleading. I think you mean it has a restricted number of potential unique values, but even that is not true for *every* data type. How many unique GUIDs would be the limit? Far more than you could ever fit on any disk currently in production, that's for sure. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand GUIDs are stored as 16 bytes compared to the 8 bytes of a BIGINT.  GUIDs however have more practical limitations around performance of a system receiving a high volume of new records.  Their randomness quickly causes index fragmentation and invalidates statistic faster.  The disk limitations, both read and write are limitations in themselves. :)

Comment: Yes, I know how GUIDs are stored. My point is that not every data type has "a restricted row count" ... how many unique `NVARCHAR(MAX)` values could you come up with? Do you know the number? I don't even know if there's a computer on earth that could calculate that number, never mind store all the values. All I'm saying is that statement is misleading, that's all.

Comment: @AndriyM Floats are stored as 8 bytes, however due to their structure they are not practical for a primary key[+/-][Exponent][mantissa]

Comment: @AaronBertrand Nor is there a computer on the planet that could store the combinations, thus making it a legitimate row count limitation. :)

Comment: If you only mean to talk about data types that are practical for a primary key, I think it's important that that last sentence clarify that. Also, not because I agree for most systems, but just to introduce a contrary point of view regarding GUIDs, please read [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56467/removal-of-guids-used-for-all-pks-fks-clustered-indexes/56578#56578) and [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52601/indexing-a-pk-guid-in-sql-server-2012/56154#56154). Thomas is a pretty smart guy, even if he takes reader intelligence for granted.

Comment: @jtimperley but what is the number? See what I'm getting at?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Getting back to reality, GUIDs are great, I was simply warning of the downsides because it supported my contrary viewpoint.  As for the bigger picture they are quite relevant and should be given significant consideration if you think your system will ever have to be replicated and/or mirrored.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really think you'll get above `2,147,483,647` rows? I doubt it. I wouldn't worry about it.

If you, at some point, begin to reach the limit, it should be trivial to change it to a `bigint`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big you're expecting this table to become - [take a look at the reference page for SQL Server for supported ranges](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) and you can answer the question about the need to change the data type of the PK for yourself.

If the key is really never used (not even as a foreign key) then culling it is entirely seemly.

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a primary key, so I wouldn't remove that. However, do you really think you're going to exceed to limit of 2,147,483,647 rows in your table?

If it's really a concern, you could just change your dataType to a `bigint`.

Here is also a [limits sheet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) on what SQL server can handle - that may help you get a fix on what you need to plan for.